# Information about Container Resource

Tags: winapi, networking

I'm writing a code to  enumerate the devices in a network using **WNetOpenEnum function** and **WNetEnumResource** and the msdn documentation in the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385478(v=vs.85).aspx mentions the terminology as **container resource** .I have googled and i didn't get much information on the same , please let me know what exactly **container resource** means .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like said on the manual page you linked:

> The WNetOpenEnum function is used to begin enumeration of the resources in a single container. The following examples show the hierarchical structure of a Microsoft LAN Manager network and a Novell NetWare network and identify the containers.
>
> ```
> LanMan (container, in this case the provider) 
>   ACCOUNTING (container, in this case the domain) 
>     \\ACCTSPAY (container, in this case the server) 
>       PAYFILES (disk) 
>       LASERJET (print)
> ```

Here the containers are `LanMan`, `ACCOUNTING` and `\\ACCTSPAY`.

> ```
> NetWare (container, in this case the provider) 
>   MARKETING (container, in this case the server) 
>     SYS (disk, first one on any NetWare server) 
>     ANOTHERVOLUME (disk) 
>     LASERJET (print)
> ```

Here `NetWare` and `MARKETING` are containers.

Comment: I did read this , does print and disk resources come as container resources ?

Comment: No, those are print and disk resources.

Comment: So it means to say that the function will enumerate all the devices in a container , that means a domain .